# Can somebody explain this batch code for extracting specific file from archive

Tags: windows, batch-file, archive

The below code extracts files from within the archive in another location, can somebody explain what exactly is going on in the program.

```
@echo off

if "%1" == "" GOTO error 
if "%2" == "" GOTO error

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=^" %%G IN (%1) DO call 7za.exe e %%G  %%H  -o%2  -y 

:error 
@echo usage : jobextract.bat (inputFile.txt) (o/p dir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation:

`@echo off` - turns command echoing off.  See `echo /?`

`if "%1" == "" GOTO error` - if the first parameter passed into the script is blank, goto (and skip everything in between) a label named `error`
`if "%2" == "" GOTO error` - if the second parameter passed into the script is blank, goto (and skip everything in between) a label named `error`

`FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=^" %%G` - for the next two items (tokens) that are seperated by a `^` (caret), starting with a variable named `%%G`
`IN (%1)` - in the following input `(parameter 1)`
`DO call` - run the following
`7za.exe e %%G  %%H  -o%2  -y` -  running `7za.exe1` with `e` (extract) `%%G` (first token from the `for /f`) `%%H` (second token from the `for /f`) `-o%2` (output to the directory that was put in as a second parameter in the script) `-y` (yes to overwrite)

`:error` - this is the error label
`@echo usage : jobextract.bat (inputFile.txt) (o/p dir)` print the following to the screen: usage : jobextract.bat (inputFile.txt) (o/p dir)

Here's more info on for loops: [LINK](http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm) and/or `for /?`
Here's info on `goto` and labels: [LINK](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/goto.php) and/or `goto /?`